# Bootstrap dropdown menu not staying open when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on an outdated website using Bootstrap 3.3, there is an issue when hovering the navigation bar dropdown menus. Dropdown menu's outside of the navbar work as expected.

Issue occurs when I click the dropdown button it does not force open the dropdown menu, when I hover off the dropdown menu content the menu closes. I need the menu to stay open even when I'm no longer hovering over the content. 
Example is on my website, I tried creating a snippet but couldn't minify where the issue was so it was to large.

[www.buildingims.com/gce](http://www.buildingims.com/gce)

Comment: Where is the example on your website? "Industry" dropdown seems to work ok, at least in Firefox.

Comment: @dave sorry about that, the link was to the wrong directory. I fixed the Link

Comment: Great @Max Seems like the problem has been solved.

Comment: @Hamadkhan How did you solve the problem?

Comment: @Max You are using an outdated Version of Jquery for your Bootstrap, kindly update your Jquery to 2.2 or > . It will be solved, i have checked that too. If any problem persist kindly let me know. Thank You

Comment: BTW I am trying to send you proper code for the Same Version also

Comment: @Hamadkhan I just updated jQuery to 2.2 and my website will not load.

Comment: @Hamadkhan No need to send proper code, I didn't realize jQuery was outdated I would rather just use a updated version then fix the older version.

Comment: @Max You have jquery UI and Fancy box Using. But let it leave for now , just upgrade your Bootstrap to Latest Bootstrap 3.7 Version and see the Magic :)

Comment: Also kindly do not try it on your live Server use to modify a copy of the code.

Comment: Hopefully your problem will solve brother.

Comment: @Hamadkhan I appreciate the help, but after upgrading the bootstrap CSS, the navbar completely disappeared.

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but it looks like there may be some conflict between bootstrap another css file called responsive.css. That file looks like it may be affecting visibility and opacity properties of <ul> and <li> elements at the same time as bootstrap.

Comment: @dave823 Thank you, the problem is coming from responsive.css.

Comment: @dave823 After I updated bootstrap and jQuery I tryed removing that class but yet removing that class completely removed all responsiveness from the site, even while using bootstrap and jQuery CDNs.